# Cleaned and built jar from netbeans not working with sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I have created a project in netbeans which connects to a sqlite database. So the project work fine in netbeans.

After I cleaned and built it and putting the sqlite database in the `dist` folder, the jar can't connect to the database.

I want to know what is the problem.

Comment: Please tell us, what the problem is. There will be an exception. Please add that to your question.

Comment: I don't really know the first interface is a login page. So I put my username and my password and nothing happens.